# Safari Repeating-y Background stretching width

Tags: android, css, background, safari

I have an image for the background of the site http://www.myscholly.com and it renders fine in  firefox and chrome. However when loading in Safari, it stretches the background image instead of applying the repeat-y property. This also happens on android also. Why doesn't it repeat properly? Is it a syntax issue?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The issue was the html5 property

> -webkit-background-size: cover;

which forced the background image to expand to the page width.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the background-image applied to the html tag, only the body tag. Try applying all the styles on the htmlta styles on the body tag and then create a wrapper around your content for the the current body styles.